# Is there any documentation for TrySZIndexOf?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I was looking at the implementation of the Remove method of the [Generic List in Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646). I wanted to find out if that method has some clever way of finding the item to be removed that is faster than just iterating through all the items (the answer appears to be "no"). I saw that List.Remove calls [Array.IndexOf](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,156e066ecc4ccedf) to find the item, and Array.IndexOf first tries to use a native method called TrySZIndexOf to find the item.

```
// Try calling a quick native method to handle primitive types.
int retVal;
bool r = TrySZIndexOf(array, startIndex, count, value, out retVal);
if (r)
    return retVal;
```

The declaration of TrySZIndexOf is

```
private static extern bool TrySZIndexOf(Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex, int count, Object value, out int retVal);
```

If TrySZIndexOf returns False, Array.IndexOf iterates through all the items in the array.

The comments suggest that TrySZIndexOf is an optimised method of searching an array of primitive types. Can anyone describe how this method works, or point to some documentation?

Comment: You can have a look here: https://github.com/gbarnett/shared-source-cli-2.0/blob/master/clr/src/vm/comarrayhelpers.cpp

Comment: Thanks Magnus. That appears to be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the link that Magnus posted:

`TrySZIndexOf` uses a native method which, if you're using a native type, will use `memchr` for types that fit into a single byte or another natively implemented function for types wider than 1 byte to very quickly find out the address of the item you're looking for.

The method returns false if the type is not a native type (or just otherwise not supported by the function).  In that case, there's just a brute force attempt to iterate the list/array.